# Formato de columnas con col_types

Tags: r

Tengo un fichero con muchas columnas. Al cargarlo hay dos variables que me las pone con formato lógico, pero las quiero como texto.

No quiero definir todas todas las columnas con **col_types** pq son muchas, solo las 2 que me dan problemas. Algo así como:

```
read.delim("datos.csv",header=T, sep=c('|'), 
           col_types = cols(ESTADO1 = col_character(),
                            ESTADO2 = col_character() ))
```

pero esto no funciona.

Comment: Si tu tabla es `df`, y pones `df$ESTADO1 <- as.character(df$ESTADO1)`, ¿te funciona?

Comment: En esa columna tengo puesto la letra T, al leer el fichero con read.deLim me lo cambia a TRUE, si hago lo de as.character(df$ESTADO1) me lo sigue dejando como "TRUE". Podría reemplazar los TRUE por T. Pero me gustaría saber como hacerlo al leer el fichero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamentablemente con `read.delim()` y `colClasses` solo podrías configurar "character" para todas las columnas o escribir el tipo para cada una. Pero nada te impide hacer una doble lectura, la primera para leer los "tipos" de columna y ajustar el tipo de la que quieras y luego hacer la lectura definitiva:

```
fichero <- read.delim("fichero.csv", 
                      header=T, 
                      sep='|',
                      nrows = 10) # No haría falta leer todo el archivo

classes <- sapply(fichero, class)
classes["logico"] <- "character" # Seteamos por nombre de columna el tipo adecuado

fichero <- read.delim("fichero.csv", 
                      header=T, 
                      sep='|',
                      colClasses = classes)
```

fuente: [Using colClasses to Load Data More Quickly in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/09/using-colclasses-to-load-data-more-quickly-in-r/)

De todas formas, te comento que específicamente lo que buscas podrías hacerlo usando el paquete `reader`:

```
library(readr)
fichero <- read_delim("fichero.csv", 
                      delim = "|", 
                      col_types = cols(logico = col_character()))
```